# Snapping points to Polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, snapping

Can QGIS automatically snap points to a polygon in a layer?  From that can the points then be put into a text delimited file in sequencial order?

Answer (score 1):

> Can QGIS automatically snap points to a polygon in a layer?

When digitalizing : yes. You can use snapping on polygon layer to draw points on segment or node of a polygon.

> into a text delimited file in sequencial order?

You mean : draw automatically points on a polygon from a csv ? I guess you have to get first the coordinates of nodes (or spot on segment) of the polygon you want the points to be snapped to.

I hope I help you.